# Python выдает ошибку json.decoder.JSONDecodeError при создании ТГ бота

Tags: python, json, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Всем привет, я только начинаю изучать python. Решил сделать тг бота, который присылает рандомные анекдоты. Взял апи из открытых источников, через браузер страница открывается(http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1). Ошибка json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 73 (char 72), насколько я понимаю что-то не так с какими-то символами на самом сайте? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

```
import telebot
import requests
import json

bot = telebot.TeleBot('?????')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "This joke for you")
    joke = requests.get('http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1')
    jsonjoke = json.loads(joke.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, jsonjoke)



bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сайт `http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1` отправляет кривой JSON.

Данный код вам поможет убрать лишние символы

```
import telebot
import requests
import json
import re

bot = telebot.TeleBot('?????')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "This joke for you")
    joke = requests.get('http://rzhunemogu.ru/RandJSON.aspx?CType=1')
    jsonjoke = json.loads(re.sub(r'[\f\n\r\t\v]','',joke.text))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, jsonjoke['content'])



bot.polling()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Если не затруднит, не могли бы подсказать, это какой-то стандартный шаблон `(re.sub(r'[\f\n\r\t\v]','',joke.text)`? и как вы поняли что кривой json? С помощью консоли разработчика в браузере?

Comment: (re.sub(r'[\f\n\r\t\v]','',joke.text) - этой строкой вы по сути убрали пробелы, верно?

Comment: Все верно. Кривость JSON обнаружил с помощью отладчика